# Multhithreading, sockets

Tags: multithreading, sockets, winsock

I have manualy writing class for WinSock. My program have more that one threads. I use to synchronize objects(example std::queue) with critical sections. 
But I have errors in my socket class:

```
iResult = getaddrinfo(host.c_str(), port.c_str(), &hints, &(*this).addrresult); //permision error
```

In single thread mode all is OK. But if I start more that one threads, program has error. Help me.

```
int jSocket::ConnectSock(const std::string host, const std::string port)
{
    int iResult;
    struct addrinfo hints, *ptr;

    ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

    iResult = getaddrinfo(host.c_str(), port.c_str(), &hints, &(*this).addrresult);
    if (iResult != 0)
    {
        WSACleanup();
        return -1;
    }

    ptr = (*this).addrresult;
    (*this).sock = socket(ptr->ai_family, ptr->ai_socktype, ptr->ai_protocol);

    if ((*this).sock == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        freeaddrinfo(addrresult);
        WSACleanup();
        return -1;
    }

    iResult = connect((*this).sock, ptr->ai_addr, (int)ptr->ai_addrlen);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        closesocket((*this).sock);
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Sorry for my English.

Comment: More code, please. Where and how `host`, `port`, and `addrresult` are declared and used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a race on the `addrresult` member pointer. The method you posted is **[not re-entrant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reentrant_%28subroutine%29)** since it updates member variables. If you call it concurrently from multiple threads you get surprises. I'm guessing in this particular case the `addrresult` might be allocated in one thread, then allocated and overwritten in another. You might end up with a memory leak and with access to `free`-ed memory.

Comment: This method is a member of class. For each thread program created new class object. Why addresult memory relocated?

Comment: function_check - this funtion use socket, she created new object for socket. function_run - this function is multithreads, she use the function_check. I start program, and debuger show me error.

Comment: Again, not enough code to tell you what's wrong. Try reducing your program to a minimal sample that still exhibits the problem, then post that.